# conditional formatting in matrix with multiple datasets

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a matrix with multiple datasets in it using Lookup.

I would like to add some conditional formatting

```
Department         A1 Complete      A2 Complete       A3 Complete
HR                     90%               50%               2%
L&D                    30%               100%              15%
I.T                    65%               70%               12%
```

Ideally where anything over 80% is green, between 50% and 79% yellow and below 49% red.

This is one attempt I have made, the report runs but has no effect with the formatting

```
=switch(lookup(fields!Department.value,fields!Department.value,fields!A1.value,"Dateset1") > 80% , "Green","White")
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calculating the percentage, and how is it stored in your database, "80", "80%" or "0.8"?

Generally it's either 80 or 0.8 and the percentage is added with property formatting of the text box. 
That being the case, you should remove the % from your code and see what happens.

I tend to use custom code.

```
Function SetColour(ByVal Value As Integer) As String

Dim Ret as string
Ret = "Blue"

Dim Val As Double 

doubleVal = System.Convert.ToDouble(Variance)


if Value >= .86 then
Ret = "OliveDrab"

ElseIf Value <=.80 then 
Ret = "IndianRed"

end if

End Function
```

The colour expression is called by **Code.SetColour(me.value)**

Comment: Thanks Jon, the percentage is worked out in the query using Round and returns an integer eg 98  no decimal or percentage sign.  In report builder I have then used the custom format to get percentage sign  eg. 0\%

Comment: I have tried removing the percentage from the query and doing it as an expression in report builder but it still has no effect on the conditional formatting

Comment: Try this.

`=Switch(Fields!Department.value <= 49, "Red", Fields!Department.value >= 80, "Green", fields!Department.value > 50, "Yellow") `

Comment: For completion, and I think you may have been combing Switch and IIF in your original post.

`=IIF(Sum(Fields!Department.Value) <= 49, "Red", IIF(Sum(Fields!Department.Value) >80, "Green", "Yellow"))`

Comment: Get the error 'Report items can only refer to fields within the current dateset or scope' etc  , so added dataset at end but still get error  =switch(Fields!Total.value <=49, "Red", Fields!Total.value >=80, "Green", fields!Total.value > 50, "Yellow"),"Last7DaysDec"

Comment: The benefit of using the custom code is that it evaluates only the cell content and changes the font/background colour based on the output of whichever dataset has populated the cell.

The other option is to add a case statement in to the SQL and return the colour into a column. You can use that field in the font colour expression.

Comment: Ok, i'll give the custom code a shot, does this need to be copied into the 'Report Properties' and does it need to  have a reference added?

Comment: Should be just copy as is into the Code section (click anywhere outside of the report and it should be the top box, you'll probably need to change the values to suit and just paste  =Code.SetColour(me.value) into your textbox colour expression.

Comment: =Code.SetColour(me.value) have pasted this into the background color expression but get the error Function 'Set Colour' doesn't return a value on all code paths'   appreciate your patience with this